# Trigger an action from a TableviewCell in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm new to Swift and I'd like know how to trigger an action when a cell in my `TableviewController` is tapped. I created the configuration of my tableview completely in the `Storyboard`, so the cells were not created manually by coding. I also edited the tag-field of this cells in order to address them, but I am wondering how.

Do I have to create a new class or is it possible to write the code in the basic viewcontroller.swift - class?

I just would like to know how such Events are handled in Swift and how I can catch them and react on them.

Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: What are trying to really do and post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code to your `UITableViewController`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           //In here do whatever you want to do when the user selects a row
    }
```

Comment: Within the view controller.swift class?

Comment: Put it in the TableViewController

Comment: Sorry for asking but: "in" the table view controller? Where is that one to find?

Comment: Do you have a UITableViewController subclass?

Comment: No I do not. That was exactly the question. If such a class is required. Is it just a usual class inheriting from uitableviewcontroller?

Comment: If you do, then put it in there?

Comment: Then how are you presenting this TableVIew

Comment: Which class is controlling the tableView?

Comment: Obviously there is such a class. Would you tell me how to access it, from the storyboard. it is defnitely not listed im my project explorer

Comment: So to create a custom subclass go to File->New->File then click cocoa touch class make it a subclass of UITableViewController then click create. Next, go back to the storyboard click on the tableView and open up the identity inspector and set its custom subclass to be the name of the new class you just made.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Then I add the code you mentioned above and fill it with the appropriate lines and then it should work?

Comment: Yes, then just implement that code above inside your new class.

Comment: There is just one question left: Everything I configured in the storyboard, the cells and the segues to the other conrollers, they do not show. Do I have to hardcode everything i have done in the storyboard? Or is it possible to inerhit that things? Thank you again

Comment: So, basically, you are asking that can you make it such that whatever you see in the storyboard will also be shown on the simulator?

Comment: That was the case when the class in the identity inspector was "UITableViewController". I just would like to add the action to the existing cells and layout.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you are asking.

Comment: I created different tableviewcontrollers in the storyboard, linked them up in order to access them hirachically. that works pretty good that far. i can jump from one view to another and back. But there are other cells, that till now do not do anything. and now i would to display something (like a messagebox ) when this cells are tapped. 

Sry for being unprecise ^^

Comment: Ok, know I understand. Create a new ViewController like a messegeBox ViewController. Then, create a segue from that cell to the view controller.

Comment: XDD that comment saved my day. I am worrying about things I already did. Thank you for your endurance ^^

Comment: If you want to learn more about UITableViews then watch this video, it is very thorough and it is by Stanford University. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIwaIEfPAh8. But, first, I would recommend that you watch this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHx4nE7EMic.